# How to use SVGs with Expo-Image

Tags: react-native, expo

On the Expo-Image documentation page it says its compatible with SVG, but when i try to load a SVG with it, it is just blank. However when i use png everything works fine. Anyone know how to use SVGs with Image from expo-image?

Answer (score 0):

They are supposed to work as the other images.

If you're importing your image from your project, do not forget to use `require(...)`.

So

```
<Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={require('path/to/your/local/icon.svg'} />
```

or

```
<Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: "https://url-to-online-icon.svg" }} />
```

Comment: Still results in a blank image using require to my svg

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I got it working after I removed the metro config mods from react-native-svg.
If I just don't transform the files and then use code like shown below, it seems to work fine.

```
import SomeSvg from "~/assets/some-svg.svg";

// ...
  return <Image source={SomeSvg} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following this from [Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/ui-programming/using-svgs/#converting-individual-svg-files-for-react-native)

I've been having this issue on **Expo SDK 50** and using [React-SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true) helped. My answer is to convert your .svg file to a **React Native SVG Component**

> **Note:** you'll need to install an Expo package `npx expo install react-native-svg`.

Open [React-SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true), on the "**SVG INPUT**" tab clear the text you see, then drag-and-drop your .svg file on the "**SVG INPUT**" tab and that's it. It will generate code for you on the right tab "**JSX OUTPUT**" and also check the **Global** sidebar for extra controls like if you use typescript, also tick the **typescript** checkbox plus the "**Expand Props**" switch it to **none**. Also on the **Sidebar**, under "**SVGO**", disable it.

Now just copy and paste the code `<Svg>...</Svg>` into your component and your SVG should show/display and also adjust the height and width according to your styles.

**Example**

```
<Svg
    width={50}
    height={50}
    viewBox="0 0 500 500"
    fill="none"
>
    ...
</Svg>
```